# Pure CSS Slider Animation

Tags: css, animation, slider

I need some help
I want to make a slideshow where you can add as many pictures as you want.
But the problem is that my slider animation can't handle more then three pictures without looking bad.

Here is my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emxoXj

```css
.slides {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slidesContainer {
  width: 2400px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 8s ease infinite;
}
.slides .slide {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.slides div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #ff8330;
}
.slides div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #30ff83;
}
.slides div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #3083ff;
}
.slides div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #3083ff;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  15% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  30% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  45% {
    margin-left: -600px;
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: -600px;
  }
  75% {
    margin-left: -1200px;
  }
  90% {
    margin-left: -1200px;
  }
  105% {
    margin-left: -1800px;
  }
  120% {
    margin-left: -1800px;
  }
  135% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slidesContainer">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <div class="slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the problem but I don't know a different solution that works fine for me.

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  15% {margin-left: 0px;}
  30% {margin-left: 0px;}
  45% {margin-left: -600px;}
  60% {margin-left: -600px;}
  75% {margin-left: -1200px;}
  90% {margin-left: -1200px;}
  105% {margin-left: -1800px;}
  120% {margin-left: -1800px;}
  135% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , you can add as many slides as you want just add delay for each image here like:

---

if u have **5 images** css will be (5x4=20s delay)

```
img:nth-child(5){-webkit-animation-delay:20s;}
```

---

if u have **6 images** css will be (6x4=24s delay)

```
img:nth-child(6){-webkit-animation-delay:24s;}
```

---

```css
body{background:#eee;}

.slider{
  margin:10px auto;
  width:500px;
  height:320px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;

}
.photo{
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation:round 16s infinite;
  opacity:0;
  width:100%;
  
}
@-webkit-keyframes round{   
  25%{opacity:1;}
  40%{opacity:0;}
} 

img:nth-child(4){-webkit-animation-delay:0s;}
img:nth-child(3){-webkit-animation-delay:4s;}
img:nth-child(2){-webkit-animation-delay:8s;}
img:nth-child(1){-webkit-animation-delay:12s;}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8241/8562523343_9bb49b7b7b.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8320/8035372009_7075c719d9.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8465/8113424031_72048dd887.jpg" alt="" />
  <img class='photo'  src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8517/8562729616_35b1384aa1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but i need a Slider who runs automatically

Comment: Much thanks for your work but it dosent runs automatically for me?

Comment: @Berchtesgaden happy to help, you can accept the answer if it is helpful to you! that will help me to help others here!